# How to display associated content through shared taxonomy?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have two content types, 'Topic Summary' and 'Clip Page.' Both can share the same taxonomy. For example, they might share the taxonomy 'raccoons.'

When a user clicks on a 'topic summary' I would like to display links to the related 'clip pages' through their shared taxonomy in a block underneath the content of the 'topic summary.'

I've tried doing this using views and contextual filters but I'm having no luck. I wonder if anyone could tell me how do achieve this? Specifically, it would be good to know the Drupal way of doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working with 'Views Node Taxonomy Filter.' It allows you to filter by the taxonomy of the current node and appears to be under active development.

http://drupal.org/project/vntf

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your situation correctly you want to display a list of clip pages grouped by topic summary.

In Drupal 6 you can use the http://drupal.org/project/views_groupby module, in Drupal 7 it's built in to views.

HTH

Comment: Almost! An example would be, if I'm on a 'topic summary' page with the taxonomy 'raccoons', I'd also like to display links to 'clip pages' that share the taxonomy 'raccoons.' Ideally in a way that generalises across different taxonomies.